# How to autoFill the Dropdown bar State and District on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, autofill

I am trying to autofill the form so that I can save a lot of time by using javascript. I figured out the ways to fill the "Name", "Date of birth", "Father's name", "Gender" and button click events and many other things by selecting the "name" attributes of various input fields like this  ->

```
javascript:function e() { f0 = document.forms[0];
f0['ctl00$HomePageContent$ctrlTextUserName'].value="#Name";  //fills name
f0['ctl00$HomePageContent$ctrlTextPresentAddress1'].value="#address";  //fills address
f0['ctl00$HomePageContent$dec_chkbox'].click();  //button click event
}
e()
```

but can't able to figure out the **select** tags so that i can select the "States" and "District" values because district is dependent on the selected states and the input of "states" section is using some onChange attr which is firing some function.
Below codes are from the view-source of that website

```
<select 
  name="ctl00$HomePageContent$ctrlTxtPresentState" 
  id="ctl00_HomePageContent_ctrlTxtPresentState" 
  tabindex="19" 
  class="txtbox" 
  onchange="selectPresentStates();" 
  style="width:160px;">
                    <option value="-1">---Please Select---</option>

</select>
```

and the **selectPresentStates()** functions looks like this :

```
function selectPresentStates() {

            var selectedval = document.getElementById("ctl00_HomePageContent_ctrlTxtPresentState").selectedIndex - 1;

            document.getElementById("ctl00_HomePageContent_hidpresentdenState").value = states[selectedval][1];
            document.getElementById("ctl00_HomePageContent_hidpresentdenState1").value = selectedval;
            var distElem = document.getElementById("ctl00_HomePageContent_ctrlTextPresentDistrict");


            if (selectedval >= 0) {
                var j = 0;
                clearpresentDistricts();
                distElem.options[j] = new Option("---Please Select---"); j++;
                for (var i = 0; i < districts[selectedval].length; i++) {
                    distElem.options[j] = new Option(districts[selectedval][i][0]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to select states and district and change their values ?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate throught your select or do it like this:

$("#myselect option[value=3]").attr('new_value', 'new_value');

Or:

$("#myselect").val('new_value');

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as you can see there is no other "options" except the single one with value = -1  <option value="-1">---Please Select---</option>. options values dynamically changes on clicking on the dropdown menu. Can you contact me +918448774634(whatsapp)